# How to install ruby-oci8, the ruby client for oracle on debian based systems (also ubuntu)

Tags: ruby, oracle

Most information found even on the client's homepage is somehow inaccurate or outdated.
This is the straight-foward method that worked for me, and I'd like to share with you.

It would be nice if this answer can be expanded by some other system specific methods that might be harder to get it installed on.

Answer (score 10):

**Oracle ruby-oci8
Installing in Ubuntu LTS 12.04 32bit**
Updated to 64bit version. Thx [OneHoopyFrood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1795429/onehoopyfrood)

1. First, internal requirements

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   sudo apt-get install libaio-dev
   ```
2. Download oracle instant client from

   <strike>http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxsoft-082809.html</strike>
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

   You’ll need both zip files, instantclient-basic AND instantclient-sdk
3. on your machine, make yourself root (sudo su) and make the destination folders:

   ```
   mkdir /opt
   mkdir /opt/oracle
   cd /opt/oracle
   ```
4. put both files inside /opt/oracle and unzip them.

   ```
   unzip instantclient-basic*
   unzip instantclient-sdk*
   ```
5. make a symlink of instantclient for easier finding by the system

   ```
   cd /opt/oracle/instantclient10_1 
   ln -s libclntsh.so.10.1 libclntsh.so
   ```
6. Now, export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to instantclient path.

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/instantclient
   ```
7. NOW… you can install ruby-oci8

   a. if using RVM, use:

   ```
   gem install ruby-oci8
   ```

   b.- if installing to system, use:

   ```
   sudo gem install ruby-oci8
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The sudo command drops LD_LIBRARY_PATH for security reasons. Use 'sudo env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH gem install ruby-oci8' to install ruby-oci8 to system.

Comment: I'll put this here in hopes the rude comment above is deleted. 
For 64bit please download it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps to install ruby-oci8 Gem Installation in Ubuntu.

**Step 1:**
Download the basic & sdk instantclient zip files from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

```
instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

**Step 2:**
Install following packages

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libaio-dev
```

**Step 3:**
Create a folder oracle inside `/opt/`

```
mkdir /opt/oracle
```

**Step 4:**
Go to inside `/opt/oracle/`

```
cd /opt/oracle
```

**Step 5:**
Place the basic instantclient folder inside `/opt/oracle`

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.8.0.0.0dbru.zip /opt/oracle/
```

**Step 6:**
Place the sdk instantclient folder inside `/opt/oracle`

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.8.0.0.0dbru.zip /opt/oracle/
```

**Step 7:**
Unzip the basic instantclient folder

```
sudo unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

**Step 8:**
Unzip the sdk instantclient folder

```
sudo unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

**Step 9:**
Check the folders inside `/opt/oracle/`. It should now have a folder named as `instantclient_21_8`

**Step 10:**
Update the runtime link path

```
sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_8 > \
>       /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
```

**Step 11:**
Check the runtime link path, It should now return `/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_8`

```
cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf
```

**Step 12:**
Set the path in env

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_8:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Step 13:**
Check the path if set properly in env. It should now have proper value set as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_8:/opt/instantclient`

```
env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**Step 14:**
Now try by installing the gem ruby-oci8

```
gem install ruby-oci8
```

It should work now.

Comment: I would replace step 12 with `sudo ldconfig` and delete step 13.  With the ld.so.conf.d & ldconfig steps, you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.